# Can addHeaderView take TextView as argument

Tags: android, textview

In my ListActivity I'm trying to add a Header with single text.

I tried with the Layout and add with addHeaderView - success

But it requires Inflater and have to create a layout-xml

I cast the TextView to View Object

```
View v=(View)myTextView;
```

Then pass it to addHeaderView

```
myListView.addHeaderView(v);
```

I failed.
Is that possible to cast the textview ?

It shows only runtime error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the textView directly, no need to cast.

```
TextView tv = new TextView( this );
tv.setText( "Header" );
listView.addHeaderView( tv );
```

You can create a textView runtime and pass it to the headerView, but you cannot use an existing textView.

Comment: Works fine here. How do you instantiate your textView?

Comment: The error because I didn't Put Context for my Textview I initialized it with null value

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tv = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myheaderview, null);
tv.setText("My awesome headerview");
mListView.addHeader(tv);
```

Comment: This is I have tried before. It's also working. I'm lazy to create a new layout. The answer I need is @Nicholas Magnussen posted. Anyway this is also a good answer. thank you :)